# Vue effectively using computed property

Tags: vue.js, vuex, computed-properties

I have the below code in my computed property. The function is expected to get way complicated. Is it correct to have it all here? I would like to have it in my store file, but I'm not able to call a function by name from within the computed property. Any advice ?

```
computed: {
  assignValue() {
    this.valueToSet = this.value1;
    
    if (this.valueToSet < 10) {
      return "1 week"
    } else if (this.valueToSet < 20) {
      return "2 weeks"
    } else if (this.valueToSet < 30) {
      return "3 weeks"
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

To summarize, I would like to have it in my store.js (vuex), but how can I call/trigger a function by name inside "the computer property".

If it is not possible, any effective alternative? Or I should continue this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vuex itself has [getter](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html) properties that you can use with Vue component's computed property as shown in the docs.

As far as your code is concerned, there is no problem with your current approach. You should move this code to Vuex getter when you need to re-use that state in multiple components.

The only problem in your code is `this.valueToSet = this.value1;`. Computed properties should not produce a side-effect (including assignment). There is no direct harm, but it can have unintended consequences internally as computed values are cached. If you still need this part - `this.valueToSet = this.value1;` - move it to other computed property or use **watch** expression.

Comment: Thank you for the precise answer. As I understood, I can call the this.$store.getter.xxx. from within the computed property? 

Regarding (this.valueToSet = this.value1). Sure I won't use it. All will be accessed using the store.state. 

Awaiting your kind confirmation.

Comment: In the computed just replace all the expressions like `this.valueToSet < 10`, etc. with `this.value1 < 10`. The computed will automatically "watch" for `this.value1` to change.

Comment: @MEAG No, you would move all this computed code (minus that assignment line) into a getter in your store. Then you would map that getter into the computed properties in your page/component (most easily done with `...mapGetters('modulename', ['getterName'])`. You could then refer to it in your template with `{{ getterName }}`

Comment: @MEAG It is exactly like Soviut said.